# What is the right way to remove a stored procedure in liquibase

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, stored-procedures, liquibase

I have a spring boot app with liquibase folder structure as below.

```
db/
├─ changes/
│  ├─ sql/
│  │  ├─ prc_existing_to_be_deleted.sql
│  │  ├─ prc_newly_added.sql
│  ├─ stored-procs-changelog.xml
├─ changelog.xml
```

- `changelog.xml` for storing all the changes in liquibase
- `stored-procs-changelog.xml` for storing the stored procedure changelogs
- `prc_existing_to_be_deleted.sql` stored procedure that is already existing
- `prc_newly_added.sql` stored procedure that is going to be added newly.

My question here is - will liquibase automatically delete the stored procedure in `prc_existing_to_be_deleted.sql` and update its tables once I delete the file and rerun the app and everything is good? If not what is the right way to delete the stored procedure in that file.

Answer (score 1):

No, Liquibase will not drop anything if you just remove the file with changeSets.

If you want to alter your DB somehow, you need to write a corresponding changeSet for it.

If we're talking about procedures, there's a `dropProcedure` change. Check out the docs and examples [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/drop-procedure.html)